# Connecting two nodes in Java

Tags: java, list, nodes, connect

So for a project I have to create two nodes, which I have done, and then create a separate class with a constructor that takes the two nodes as arguments and then connects/links them. Here is my class creating a node.

```
package Linear;

public class StringNode {

public String data;

public StringNode next;

public StringNode(String data, StringNode next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;

}

public String toString() {
    return data + "";

}
public static void main(String[] args) {


StringNode newNode = new StringNode("Everest", null);
System.out.println(newNode);

StringNode newNode2 = new StringNode("Kilimanjaro", null);
System.out.println(newNode2);


    }
}
```

So the two nodes created here are called Everest and Kilomanjaro, I need to connect these nodes using a constructor but I am having problems doing so. I have something like this, but it's throwing up errors in the arguments when I try to call it (Edgelist(StringNode, StringNode) is undefined).

```
package Linear;

public class EdgeList {



public StringNode insert(StringNode firstNode, StringNode secondNode) {
        secondNode.next = insert(firstNode, secondNode.next);



    return secondNode;


    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do some sort of strange recursive behavior in `insert()`?

Comment: What is the code that is giving you the error? From your description, it sounds like you are trying to call a constructor but I don't see that constructor defined.

Comment: @twinklehawk Well I was trying to call EdgeList connector = new EdgeList(newNode, newNode2); in another the node class but obviously it wasn't working. I'm just having trouble in making a constructor that links the two nodes and I can't find any resources to help me

Comment: Do you have the EdgeList constructor that accepts two StringNode objects defined anywhere? Please edit your question to include the relevant code

Comment: @EvanWeissburg I was just trying to create a constructor that connects the two nodes but I'm very new to Java and I'm having trouble doing it

Comment: @twinklehawk No, I don't, this is all of my code, I don't know how to make it accept two StringNode arguments

Answer (score 2):

```
Edgelist(StringNode, StringNode)
```

It looks like constructor, which you are not defined in the class. So if there is no constructor - it couldn't be called.

You can create setter (or use variables while they are public) and call setters for both nodes after initializing.

```
StringNode newNode = new StringNode("Everest", null);
StringNode newNode2 = new StringNode("Kilimanjaro", null);

newNode.setNext(newNode2);
newNode2.setNext(newNode);
```

Or, if you really need new class for this, you can do something like that:

```
public class EdgeList {
    public EdgeList(StringNode firstNode, StringNode secondNode) {
        secondNode.next = firstNode;
        firstNode.next = secondNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, so EdgeList doesn't need to return anything?

Comment: Actually I think it's working now, thank you so much. If I use System.out.println("Next node: " + newNode.next); it shows that the next node is Kilimanjaro